# Laravel pass config data into trait's property

Tags: php, laravel

```
trait Foo {
    private $url = config('api.url');

}
```

I have a url data set inside of config, however I need to put this value into trait's property. But it's not working. anyone know how to solve this problem?

what I did now is put construct inside of trait

```
public function __construct(){
        $this->url = config('api.url');
    }
```

Comment: How are you using the trait? Post the code

Comment: i did, got error syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not about traits, it's about php `OOP` nature itself:

here is the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may
>   include an initialization, **but this initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
>   must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**

from the docs example:

```
// invalid property declarations:
public $var4 = self::myStaticMethod();
public $var5 = $myVar;
```

Comment: oh ok, i will just put __construct and update the value